What exactly is a true distribution in ML problems?
I define a classification problem as a problem of calculating a function $h$ that approximates a function $f$ that classifies data. The approximation is calculated by taking a set of training samples and their classifications by $f$ and training a model on that data set. You could say the training set is "described" by $f$ in a way.
For the training of a model I am now trying to define what an error and loss is. In the book "Artifical Intelligence A modern Approach" on p. 688 the empirical loss (which is the training loss, as I understand it) is defined as follows:
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in E}L(y,h(x))\frac{1}{N}
$$
$E$ is the train set and $N$ is the number of samples in the train set. In other words, the empirical loss is a measure of how "far off" each prediction of a training sample is compared to the true label. We get this overall loss by summing up all loss values for each training sample and average it.
According to that definition I would define the generalization loss as a measure of how "far off" each prediction of an unknown sample is compared to the true label. This is usually done by a test set $T$.
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in T}L(y,h(x))\frac{1}{N}
$$
In "Artifical Intelligence A modern Approach" on p. 688 a more general definition is presented:
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in \mathcal{E}}L(y,h(x))P(x,y)
$$
$\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all possible input-output examples and $P(x,y)$ is taken from a probability distribution $\textbf{P}(X,Y)$.
As I understand it $P(x,y)$ is the probability that $x$ is labeled with $y$. In a classification problem $\textbf{P}(X,Y)$ as the true distribution contains a probability of $1$ if $y$ is the correct label of $x$ and $0$ otherwise for every possible pair $(x,y)$. But in a case where $P(x,y) = 0$, the generalization loss would always be $0$ so I must have something wrong in my understanding.
Edit: I indeed had something wrong in my understanding of probability distributions in this context, but am still confused about the notation of $P(x,y)$ of the third definition.
When we talk about the distribution of some sort of problem, do we talk about
a) the proabilities $P(x,y)$ of data examples $(x,y)$ occuring or
b) the probabilities $P(y)$ of certain classes $y$ occuring?
Let's say for example we have a problem that is represented by the following data set:
$$\{(1,Dog), (2,Dog), (3,Cat), (4,Cat), (5,Dog)\}$$
In this case according to a) we would have $P(1,Dog)=0.2$ and according to b) we would have $P(1,Dog)=0.6$.
So my question would be: Why is the $x$ included in $P(x,y)$ in the third definition and does it make any difference?

We can talk about both of these probabilities and they have a different meaning. Assuming discrete variables:

$P(y)$ is the class probability - the proportion of the population that is in class $y$.

$P(x,y)$ is the joint probability of seeing $x$ and $y$ - the proportion of the population that is in class $y$ and has attribute(s) $x$.


For example, let's assume we have a population of 100 animals (the $y$ variable) consisting of 40 cats and 60 dogs and we have a single predictor ($x$) variable - the type of ear, which can be pointy or floppy.
Now let's assume our population has the following distribution:



animal
pointy ears
floppy ears




cats
35
5


dogs
10
50



From this, we get the following probabilities:



class probabilities
joint probabilities




P(y=cat) = 40/100 = 0.4
P(x=pointy, y=cat) = 35/100 = 0.35



P(x=floppy, y=cat) = 5/100  = 0.05


P(y=dog) = 60/100 = 0.6
P(x=pointy, y=dog) = 10/100 = 0.1



P(x=floppy, y=dog) = 50/100 = 0.5



However, in the context of calculating the model loss, we use the joint probabilities. Assume we have a simple model ($h$) to decide whether a member of our population is a cat or dog: if it has pointy ears it's a cat and if it has floppy ears it's a dog.
We can summarizing the model results as follows:



animal
ear type
number
model prediction




cat
pointy
35
cat


cat
floppy
5
dog


dog
pointy
10
cat


dog
floppy
50
dog



Obviously, using this model we will predict the incorrect animal 15 times out of 100, so the 0-1 loss is 0.15 (when expressed as a proportion).
Using the 3rd equation for the loss in the question, we calculate our loss as the sum of the model loss for all the different combinations of the class and predictor variables $\times$ the probability of each combination occurring (which is the joint probability $P(x,y)$):

$L(y=cat, h(x=pointy)) \times P(x=pointy, y=cat) = 0 \times 0.35 = 0$
$L(y=cat, h(x=floppy)) \times P(x=floppy, y=cat) = 1 \times 0.05 = 0.05$
$L(y=dog, h(x=pointy)) \times P(x=pointy, y=dog) = 1 \times 0.1 = 0.1$
$L(y=dog, h(x=floppy)) \times P(x=floppy, y=dog) = 0 \times 0.5 = 0$

where $h$ is the model, which again comes to 0.15, as expected.

Thanks for this example, that helps.
Am I correct in assuming that the x in an example (x,y) can also be a feature vector, instead of one feature like in your example?

@Leandro: Yes, I've just used a single feature for simplicity. If you have multiple feature, the number of possible combinations and therefore the number of joint probabilities can get very large.
